# Running a batch file for all user profiles

Tags: arrays, batch-file, vbscript, user-profile, citrix

I am trying to cleanup all of our user profiles. I have a batch file written that will delete all files/directories for the logged in user when it's run. However we are wanting to have this run for all user's during the weekend when they aren't logged in. I'm new to Vb Script as well as coding in general. Different thoughts to resolve this would be to run a loop-back of all our user profiles which will write each username found to an array. Then have the batch file call each name from the array to go through and run the delete process. However like I said I'm very new and inexperienced to Arrays and Loop-backs.

This is the Batch file I have written:

```
MOVE "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions" "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\"
MOVE "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Bookmarks" "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome"
Move "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Bookmarks.bak" "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome"
Move "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Preferences" "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome"
Move "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\History-journal" "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome"
Move "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\History" "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome"
del /S /Q "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\*"
MOVE "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Bookmarks" "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\"
MOVE "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Bookmarks.bak" "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\"
MOVE "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Preferences" "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\"
MOVE "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Extensions" "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\"
MOVE "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\History-journal" "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\"
MOVE "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\History" "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\"
```

I'm assuming that the %username% will have to be modified to instead call from the array. 
Any help you can give regarding any part of the process would be much appreciated. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** Now I know what you want for.
I changed all `%username%` to `%%a` since we get usernames from *ALL_USERNAME_ARE_STORED_HERE.txt* line by line.

```
@Echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (ALL_USERNAME_ARE_STORED_HERE.txt) do (
    MOVE "C:\Users\%%a\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions" "C:\Users\%%a\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\"
    MOVE "C:\Users\%%a\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Bookmarks" "C:\Users\%%a\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome"
    Move "C:\Users\%%a\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Bookmarks.bak" "C:\Users\%%a\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome"
    Move "C:\Users\%%a\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Preferences" "C:\Users\%%a\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome"
    Move "C:\Users\%%a\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\History-journal" "C:\Users\%%a\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome"
    Move "C:\Users\%%a\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\History" "C:\Users\%%a\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome"
    del /S /Q "C:\Users\%%a\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\*"
    MOVE "C:\Users\%%a\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Bookmarks" "C:\Users\%%a\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\"
    MOVE "C:\Users\%%a\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Bookmarks.bak" "C:\Users\%%a\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\"
    MOVE "C:\Users\%%a\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Preferences" "C:\Users\%%aAppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\"
    MOVE "C:\Users\%%a\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Extensions" "C:\Users\%%a\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\"
    MOVE "C:\Users\%%a\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\History-journal" "C:\Users\%%a\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\"
    MOVE "C:\Users\%%a\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\History" "C:\Users\%%a\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\"
)

pause >nul
```

Let me know If I misunderstood you again...
*Double check all `%username%` are changed to `%%a`.

Comment: Thank you for the script. This will create a dynamic array that has an increasing limit? Like I said I'm a newbie to this kind of stuff so I want to understand it as well as I can.
why the following lines?:
echo %array[0]%
echo %array[4]%
echo %array[9]%
meaning why just 0, 4, 9?

Comment: Also, how would I target all usernames to be saved to a text file? I'm researching around now trying to figure that command out, rather than having to go through and type out each user.

Comment: `echo` is just an example to let you see the result. Well, according to `C++`,integer type array stores 4 bytes of data (if not mistaken), so I guess there's pretty much arrays before it completely filled up your hard drive :)

Comment: Where you get those usernames? By `set /p` ?

Comment: Again thank you. I will mess around with this and update what I find/works. :D

Comment: I have the all the usernames in a text file now. The command you provided is pointing at that text file. The next step now is how to have my initial batch file call into this array batch so that each user is now targeted by the purge process? @dark fang

Comment: Do you mean you use `call` in another batch file?

Comment: I haven't set the call up yet. But i have my batch made that will purge profiles. I need to write something within that which will call from the array script that you provided so that my initial batch file can target every user profile.

Comment: You mean like : `call Another_Batch.bat` from this script? I don't get it anyway.

Comment: Like my initial question said. I have a batch file that needs to run for all users while they are logged off. I created a text file that has all the users in it. I took the script that you provided and pointed it at that file. I was under the assumption that I would have to make what you provided point to what I already had. 
But are you saying to just drop the script that you provided somewhere within my initial batch file?

Comment: I was wondering something similar. Your edited script no longer includes the set array command. Isn't that necessary in conjunction with pulling from the .txt file? 
I was thinking that I could drop the following line:
`call "\\uscinw2k301\public\IT\Scripts\Profile Cleanup\ChromePurge.bat"`
put this at the end of the (). so on the line just after "set /a increment+=1"
or do I not have this understood?

Comment: What does *ChromePurge.bat* do? Btw, `%%a` will automatically set the each line (each username) from the txt file

Comment: chromepurge.bat is the batch file I posted at the top. So if I modify that batch by changing all %username% to %%a
and then run the second batch file that way i put in the above comment, it would achieve what I'm looking at?

Comment: Yeap, but you have to save the 2nd batch to *ChromePurge.bat* first.

Comment: Thank you for all the help. I will try to figure out how to pass that parameter. Because it is my understanding that as it stands, it won't complete yet. I still need to now, call each user from that array one by one, and have that variable sent into the the chromepurge.bat file. Then the script can call the chromepurge.bat which will purge out the chrome files for that variable (user) and then have it move onto the next variable (user) for the same process

Comment: Why do you insist using arrays? I thought this script will achieve what you want?

Comment: I don't insist on doing any particular way. That is how my boss recommend I look into doing it. I just want to get the job done. So long as each user has their Chrome file purged of everything except for the 4 things I preserve in my batch file, I'm a happy camper.